# Howto set backgroundColor (tintColor) on UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.3, xcode4.5, tintcolor

I hope you can help me to set the background color of my controller.

The strange thing is when I build my code in Xcode 4.5.2 it look like the picture below. As you can see the background color is gone it should be (yellow) as the next picture
[image: Build with Xcode 4.5.2]

When I build my code in Xcode 4.3.3 it look like the picture below. And this is how it should look.
[image: Build with Xcode 4.3.3]

My code is like this:

------------------InstantCabAppDelegate.m file-----------START-------

```
//InstantCabAppDelegate.m file

orderController = [[OrderController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Order2" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* firstnavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:orderController];
```

------------------OrderController2.m file-----------START-------

```
//OrderController2.m file

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:TABLE_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:TABLE_VIEW_SEPARATOR_COLOR];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-nologo"]];

    UIView *logoParentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 75)];
    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_order_page"]];
    CGRect logoViewFrame = logoView.frame;
    logoViewFrame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (logoViewFrame.size.width / 2);
    logoViewFrame.origin.y = 8;
    [logoView setFrame:logoViewFrame];
    [logoParentView addSubview:logoView];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = logoParentView;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 50;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:NAVIGATION_BAR_TINT_COLOR];

    [[MyLocation singleton] setDelegate:self];
    [self reset];

    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];

    UIButton *orderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [orderButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, footerView.frame.size.width - 10, 50)];

    [orderButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [orderButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [orderButton setTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"kOrderOrderTaxiAlt", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[orderButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:orderButton.titleLabel.font.pointSize]];
    [orderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkOrder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [footerView addSubview:orderButton];
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:footerView];

    isShowingModalViewController = NO;
}
```

Comment: Has no one seen this wird behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

**I got this from Apple support:**

UITableView applies a background view to itself when the table view's style is set to UITableViewStyleGrouped.  The background view is used to draw the default pattern associated with that style table view but it also covers any custom background color that has been set.  You can remove this background view by calling self.tableView.backgroundView = nil; from within viewDidLoad.  Doing so will make your custom background color visible again.

? Apple Inc. | Apple Developer Technical Support